# C++ Quicksorting a string array read from a txt file

Tags: c++, string, sorting, segmentation-fault

I'm currently training myself for sorting algorithms, and I got a problem with quicksorting a string array.

My code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void strQsrt(string * ary, int l, int r);

int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  string temp;
  string ary[100];

  ifstream input("inputtext.txt");
  while( !input.eof() )
  {
    input >> ary[i];
    cout << i+1 << " : " << ary[i] << endl;
    i++;
  };
  cout << endl;

  strQsrt(ary, 0, 99);

  return 0;
}

void strQsrt(string * ary, int l, int r)
{
  int i=l, j=r;
  string temp;
  string mid=ary[ (l+r)/2 ];

  while( i <= j )
  {
    while( ary[i] < mid )
    {
      i++;
    };
    while( ary[j] > mid )
    {
      j++;
    };
    if( i <= j )
    {
      temp = ary[i];
      ary[i] = ary[j];
      ary[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j++;
    };
  };

  if( l < j )
  {
    strQsrt(ary, l, j);
  };
  if( i < r )
  {
    strQsrt(ary, i, r);
  };

  for( int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
  {
    cout << c+1 << " : " << ary[c] << endl;
  };
}
```

I was trying to sort one hundred random names in alphabetical order. This code compiles properly, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. When I run this program in CygWin, it looks like this:

```
$ ./binarysearch.exe
1 : Brittny
2 : Margarett
3 : Mariella
4 : Amanda
5 : Isabella
6 : Meghan
7 : Junior
8 : Pamela
9 : Arnette
10 : Toi
11 : Serina
12 : Kim
13 : Peggy
14 : Ellena
15 : Paul
16 : Alica
17 : Keli
18 : Dorine
19 : Conception
20 : Ora
21 : Nakia
22 : Elmer
23 : Teddy
24 : Jacinda
25 : Paris
26 : Beula
27 : Lavette
28 : Marla
29 : Brandi
30 : Neva
31 : Niesha
32 : Dustin
33 : Lane
34 : Season
35 : Norene
36 : Karisa
37 : Johnathon
38 : Dan
39 : Lavenia
40 : Zonia
41 : Chau
42 : Stanton
43 : Patty
44 : Shyla
45 : Elfriede
46 : Leida
47 : Fawn
48 : Karrie
49 : Joanne
50 : Rivka
51 : Roslyn
52 : Cris
53 : Enola
54 : Rafaela
55 : Bula
56 : Teressa
57 : Jackqueline
58 : Antoinette
59 : Lizeth
60 : Torie
61 : Farrah
62 : Stefani
63 : Tamisha
64 : Masako
65 : Margarita
66 : Sandi
67 : Beau
68 : Candelaria
69 : Lia
70 : Tamra
71 : Anne
72 : Lona
73 : Odell
74 : Alethia
75 : Tama
76 : Lina
77 : Carli
78 : Viviana
79 : Dorothy
80 : Rima
81 : Robert
82 : Karolyn
83 : Silvana
84 : Florine
85 : Kandice
86 : Ernesto
87 : Nola
88 : Jasper
89 : Dalia
90 : Lashunda
91 : Ralph
92 : Delois
93 : Mathew
94 : Doretta
95 : Aron
96 : Barrie
97 : Hazel
98 : Lino
99 : Danna
100 : Nancy

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know segmentation fault is from some kind of bad pointer usage, but I don't think I can find where I messed it up. Where did I do wrong? How can I deal with this error?

Comment: _"but I don't think I can find where I messed it up"_ Running your code in the debugger, is extremly helpful to find out.

Comment: Your array "ary" can store 100 strings only, but you iterate until EOF of input file, so storing string number 101 causes writing over array bounds

Comment: *This code compiles properly, but I keep getting a segmentation fault.* -- Compiling properly has nothing to do with whether your program has bugs or not.  If all we had to do to get bug-free programs is to "compile properly", then no program would have bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting initial valule of j in strQsrt function to 99. Then you are incrementing that value. Segmentation fault pops out when j =101, that is past the `ary` size. If you want to see for yourself modyfy your function to

```
    void strQsrt(string * ary, int l, int r)
{
  int i=l, j=r;
  string temp;
  string mid=ary[ (l+r)/2 ];


  while( i <= j )
  {
    while( ary[i] < mid )
    {
      i++;
    }
    while( ary[j] > mid )
    {
        cout<<"j="<<j<<endl;
      j++;
    }
    if( i <= j )
    {
      temp = ary[i];
      ary[i] = ary[j];
      ary[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j++;
    }
  }


  if( l < j )
  {
    strQsrt(ary, l, j);
  };
  if( i < r )
  {
    strQsrt(ary, i, r);
  };

  for( int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
  {

    cout << c+1 << " : " << ary[c] << endl;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thx, I fixed the problem.

Comment: If this was the solution to your problem please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
while( !input.eof() )
  {
    input >> ary[i];
    cout << i+1 << " : " << ary[i] << endl;
    i++; <------- when this gets to 100, what happens on next iteration?
  };
```

your

```
 string ary[100];
```

goes from 0 to 99 for 100 elements.
Changing the code to the following

```
while( i < 100 && !input.eof() )
  {
    input >> ary[i];
    cout << i+1 << " : " << ary[i] << endl;
    i++;
  };
```

avoids crashes during read of data.

Comment: It actually should be `while( !input && i < 100)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, if reading the next would cause a crash, shouldn't I check that first as it makes `!input` rather irrelevant?